# Not able to migrate DB, using Python's manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, django, linux

I want to migrate a model in the database, so I am using this command in my active environment:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

But it gives me this error:

```
File "manage.py", line 14
  ) from exc
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere in your code. The message does give more details.

Comment: You are using Python 2, but your version of Django requires Python 3. Make sure you have activated your Python 3 environment. You can use `which python` to check what `python` is on your path.

Comment: in ```which python``` its showing ```/usr/bin/python```

Answer (score 0):

That is a Python 3 `manage.py` file, so you might just need to type `python3 manage.py makemigrations`, or you might need to install `python3`.

If you are using virtual environments then you probably just need to run the `bin/activate` of your virtual environment.

Comment: its taking ```/usr/bin/python
``` from where I can change it?

Comment: Right, that is python2. You need python3. Either find it (like try typing `python3`) or install it.